# Modify hyphenation behavior for texts in monospaced font

Tags: hyphenation, typewriter

I'm using a monospaced font and with some effort I got it hyphenated. However the hyphenation behavior is quite strange and the right side of the document is ugly.

[image: Right side]

Is there a way to force it always hyphenate (even if there would be many `-`s) so that the right side is aligned? Simply changing `\hyphenpenalty` to 0 seems to be useless. Or is there other way to make the right side look better?

Below is a MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=1in,showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{courierten}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\ttdefault}
\frenchspacing

\usepackage{silence}%
\WarningsOff[hyphenat]
\WarningFilter{latexfont}{Some font}%
\WarningFilter{latexfont}{Font shape}%
\usepackage[htt]{hyphenat}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \sloppy%
  \hbadness=10000%
  \hyphenpenalty=0% This seems to be useless
}

\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\blindtext[10]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Normally, spaces have glue that allows text to be stretched to the margins.  In a monospaced font, the spaces won't have glue.  Thus, unless, by totally unexpected coincidence, all lines of text had a hyphenable breakpoint at the same number of characters, you won't get a flush right margin.

Comment: If you want line breaks with hyphenation if a string of characters is broken, that's possible (and there are questions here that tell how to do it), but the hyphens will be in illogical places, not breaking words at legitimate hyphenation points.  But I don't think that's what you want.  Keeping an even right margin, hyphens only at legitimate breakpoints, and neat alignment of monospace characters are incompatible conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `\spaceskip`, which overrides the font defined interword space, which has no flexibility in monospaced fonts.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=1in,showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{courierten}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\ttdefault}
\frenchspacing
\setlength{\spaceskip}{0.3em plus 0.3em minus 0.1em}
%\setlength{\xspaceskip}{1em plus 0.5em} % not used because of \frenchspacing

\usepackage{silence}%
\WarningsOff[hyphenat]
\WarningFilter{latexfont}{Some font}%
\WarningFilter{latexfont}{Font shape}%
\usepackage[htt]{hyphenat}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  %\sloppy         % why?
  %\hbadness=10000 % <- this is useless
  \hyphenpenalty=0 % <- this is not
}

\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\blindtext[10]
\end{document}
```

[image]

The setting of `\hbadness` to 10000 does nothing important. Conversely, setting `\hyphenpenalty` to 0 allows for more hyphens. Note that a trailing space ***is*** needed after the constants.

The image shows protrusion as done by `microtype`.

Without the settings to `\hyphenpenalty` and with no protrusion I get

[image]

Perhaps, the protrusion settings for the font should be slightly modified.

Here's a picture of the first lines (with protrusion on)

[image]

Quite a wall of text.

Comment: Actually the reason I did not use a flexible `\spaceskip` is because it disrupts the alignment of the characters. I thought forcing text to always hyphenate should be easy, but now it seems I was wrong.

Comment: @Jinwen If you want to keep alignment of characters, you are *forced* to use ragged right. There's no way I know of to make interword space in discrete blocks. Maybe with LuaTeX…